# Calculating days between a given date and current_timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date

I'm trying to grab the number of days left until an account expires so I can send my user an email notifying them. I have the correct "Where" statement, but I'm unsure about how to select the difference as an integer.
So far I have:

```
SELECT (DATE_EXPIRE-CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),EMAIL 
FROM [myTable] 
WHERE (DATE_EXPIRE - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP <= 10) AND (DATE_EXPIRE - CURRENT_TIMESTAMP >= 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE_EXPIRE),EMAIL 
FROM dbo.[myTable] 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE_EXPIRE) BETWEEN 1 AND 10;
```

One of the few cases where I actually advocate using BETWEEN. Though I'd still prefer setting explicit boundaries:

```
DECLARE @tomorrow DATE = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DATE_EXPIRE),EMAIL 
FROM dbo.[myTable] 
WHERE DATE_EXPIRE >= @tomorrow
AND DATE_EXPIRE < DATEADD(DAY, 10, @tomorrow);
```

You shouldn't use shorthand math (such as `datetime - integer`) because, while that works with DATETIME / SMALLDATETIME, it breaks if you change the data type to DATE, DATETIME2, etc.

For lots of my ramblings on date range queries:

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT (datediff(DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),CONCAT(YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),'-01-00')))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).